# How to remove an image from a widget gtk c?

Tags: c, widget, gtk

I am currently working on an user interface with gtk.
What I've done for now is that you can select an image from your file and display it with the button "open".
The problem is that when I open a second image it add the image to the window without removing the current one.
I would like to know how to change the displayed image when the user choose to open another image.
My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"

#include "../Threshold/delete_color.h"


#define GTK_STOCK_CANCEL ((GtkStock)"gtk-cancel")


GtkWidget *image; 
gchar* path;


void cb_quit(GtkWidget *p_widget, gpointer user_data)
{
    gtk_main_quit();
    (void)p_widget;
    (void)user_data;
}

void solve(const gchar* path)
{
    SDL_Surface* image;

    // Binarization
    image = binarization((char*) file_name);
    SDL_SaveBMP(image, "binarize.bmp");

    // Rotation
    //rotation(image);
    SDL_SaveBMP(image, "rotation.bmp");

    // Grid Detection
    SDL_SaveBMP(image, "grid.bmp");

    // Case detection
    // TODO
    
    // Get the grid.txt
    // TODO
    
    // Get the grid solution
    // TODO

    // Create the solution image
    // TODO
}
static void set_image(const gchar *file_name, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkWidget *pVBox;
    GdkPixbuf *pixbuf;
    GError *error = NULL;

    pVBox = (GtkWidget*) user_data;
    
    int width = gtk_widget_get_allocated_width(pVBox);
    int height = gtk_widget_get_allocated_height(pVBox);

    pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file("result.bmp", &error);

    if (!error)
    {
        GdkPixbuf *pixbuf_mini = NULL;
        pixbuf_mini = gdk_pixbuf_scale_simple(pixbuf,
                width,
                height - 200,
                GDK_INTERP_NEAREST);

        image = gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf(pixbuf_mini);
        gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(pVBox), image);
        gtk_widget_show(image);
    }
}

void cb_open(GtkWidget *p_widget, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkWidget *p_dialog = NULL;
    p_dialog = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new("Open file", NULL,
            GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN,
            GTK_STOCK_CANCEL, GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL,
            GTK_STOCK_OPEN, GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT,
            NULL);

    if(gtk_dialog_run (GTK_DIALOG (p_dialog)) == GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT)
    {
        gchar *file_name = NULL;
        path = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename (GTK_FILE_CHOOSER (p_dialog));
        file_name = path;
        g_print("%s\n", path);
        set_image(file_name, user_data);
        g_free (file_name), file_name = NULL;
    }

    gtk_widget_destroy(p_dialog);
    (void)p_widget;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    GtkWidget *p_window = NULL;
    GtkWidget *p_main_box = NULL;

    // Initialisation
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    // Main window
    p_window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(p_window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(p_window), 600, 400);
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (p_window), "destroy",
            G_CALLBACK (cb_quit), NULL);

    // Main container
    p_main_box = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 0);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (p_window), p_main_box);

    // Exit button
    {
        GtkWidget *p_button = NULL;
        p_button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Exit");
        g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT (p_button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (cb_quit), NULL);
        gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX (p_main_box), p_button, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    }

    // Open button
    {
        GtkWidget *p_button = NULL;
        p_button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Open");
        g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (p_button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (cb_open), (gpointer*) p_main_box);
        gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (p_main_box), p_button, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    }

    // Display
    gtk_widget_show_all(p_window);
    g_print("%s\n", path);
    gtk_main();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Where is the rest of the code? I can't reproduce your problem...

Comment: Hi @BobMorane, I added the rest of the code.

Comment: Where is `set_image`?

Comment: i added all the code now

Comment: I added the header but one refers to another file I created

Comment: you won't be able to compile because the function `binarization` is from another file that I created.

Comment: That's the reason why we appreciate to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Small enough to avoid unrelated stuff but complete enough to reproduce.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to stack overflaw I didn't know about MCVE, I will update my post in order to provide a MCVE later.

Comment: Maybe you can try my suggestions first. If the issue is solved then, we don't need more code

Comment: BTW: Why does `set_image` take a filename if it always takes the same file?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. About `set_image` I wanted to update the filename with the function `cb_open` and then use the function `set_image` with the new file name in order to display a new image.

Comment: @Nicolas The usual way to "thank" on stack overflow is to upvote the answer. I would suggest you try it! If the answer solves your problem, you can also accept it (even better in this case: upvote + answer). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try multiple approaches.

1. Remove old image and add new image
   Use `gtk_container_get_children` to retrieve your old image if present and remove it using `gtk_container_remove`. Then add as you have done before.
2. You can replace the content of the image
   Again, use `gtk_container_get_children` to retrieve your old image if present and replace the content using `gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf`.
3. (additionally to 1 or 2 above)
   You can also create an image already when you create the container and use the pointer to that image as `user_data` for your callback. That would remove the need for retrieving the child from your container.

Comment: I used a pointer to my image with user_data and it worked. Thank you.